# Relative or Absolute Percent of Changing Total?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, percentages

I don't have a math background so am lacking in intuition when it comes to problems like this.

I have X green apples out of a total of Y apples (red, green, etc). Let's say X=5 and Y=20, so I have 25% green apples.

Both X and Y can change, and I want to know if there is a way to "hold" onto this 25% number as a benchmark of sorts without the numbers messing things up. Like if Y increases to 50, then X=5 means it's now 10% of the total. If Y goes down to 10, then X is 50% of the total. If X goes up to 10 while Y stays at 20, then X is 50% of the total.

Is there any way to keep this percent of the whole "stable"? I want to use the initial 25% (X=5, Y=20) as an absolute benchmark of sorts regardless X and Y being is flux.

I hope I've explained this well and am not thinking about anything incorrectly. Thank you.